# Detecting object touch in corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

In one class, I have 2 "buttons" which are calling 2 classes like so:

```
btn1 = display.newImage("1.png")
btn2 = display.newImage("2.png")
btn1:addEventListener("touch", onSceneTouch)
btn2:addEventListener("touch", onSceneTouch2)
```

The problem with this is that the 2 methods (onSceneTouch, onSceneTouch2) do the same thing. The only difference is that it sets a flag depending on which button is touched. My methods look like this:

```
function onSceneTouch(  event )
//do something here     
end
```

I've tried searching and I found [this article](http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/07/24/detecting-object-and-screen-taps/) and tried to follow it. I added an id to 
the buttons and called them on my method but the id was nil. If I try to set a name for the button instead like: btn1.name = "name" and call self.name on my method but of course, the name returned "touch". How would I tell my method which button was touched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the article you linked to, your code should look like this:

```
function onSceneTouch(self, event)
  local button_id = self.id
  --do something here     
end
btn1 = display.newImage("1.png")
btn2 = display.newImage("2.png")
btn1.id = 'Button1'
btn2.id = 'Button2'
btn1.touch = onSceneTouch
btn2.touch = onSceneTouch
btn1:addEventListener("touch")
btn2:addEventListener("touch")
```

Doesn't it work?

Comment: I did something similar to this except for the local button_id = self.id part and it just crashed. I'll try it again now. By the way, I failed to mention, btn1 and btn2 are inside another method on the same class. Would that affect how this is supposed to work?

Comment: Ugh, I feel so ashamed of me. I think I've overlooked something. Particularly btn1.touch = onSceneTouch and the eventListener. That's what happens when you've been coding for days with barely any rest. Thanks so much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I know answer 1's example should work just fine, but it's a bit more work than doing a function listener instead of a table listener.  I would have written it like this:

```
function onSceneTouch(event)
    local target = event.target  -- this is the actual button that was touched.
    if event.phase == "ended" then
         -- do your work here 
         print(target.id) -- prints "Button1" or "Button2"
    end
    return true -- important!
end

btn1 = display.newImage("1.png")
btn2 = display.newImage("2.png")
btn1.id = 'Button1'
btn2.id = 'Button2'
btn1:addEventListener("touch", onSceneTouch)
btn2:addEventListener("touch", onSceneTouch)
```

Same thing different way.

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`Use single event listener & identify who called this using unique name
eg

```
 function onSceneTouch(  event )
        local objectName=event.target.name    
        if objectName==1 then
            flag1=true
        else
            flag2=true 
        end


    end

btn1 = display.newImage("1.png")
btn1.name=1

btn2 = display.newImage("2.png")
btn1.name=2


btn1:addEventListener("touch", onSceneTouch)
btn2:addEventListener("touch", onSceneTouch)
```